# argument of type 'int' is not iterable - Python error while writing to another file

Tags: python, list

I am opening a file and checking if that has file has "Error" keyword in it. If found, am writing the error contents as an attachment to send as an email.

```
with open(self.filePath, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.readline()
content = [i for i in content if "Error" in i]
content = "\n".join(content)
self.msg.add_attachment(content, maintype='text', subtype='plain', filename=self.filePath.split('/')[-1])
```

But am getting an error

```
argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Please advise how I can handle this. I tried adding `b"Error"`, but that was throwing an error too.

Comment: Please show the complete traceback

Comment: By the way, `readline()` only reads a single line from the file, so `for i in content` would be characters, and `"Error"` is not in a single character

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you tell me what I can modify? I tried using read() function, but it didn't work as well

Comment: `"Error" in content_file.read()` would work fine for the whole file. You need to show the full error, otherwise, we're just guessing where the problem is

Comment: Only that line of error is what i got in console.

Comment: I understand that, but the error output should also include the line number where the error happened and which file it happened in and point at the actual line

Comment: Am not seeing the line number in which the error has happened. Could you tell me how to read from a file and look for Error and add as attachment?

Comment: @vvazza: If you just want all lines from the file containing `Error`, replace `content = content_file.readline()` with `content = [line for line in content_file if b"Error" in line]` (and delete the now superfluous `content = [i for i in content if "Error" in i]`). You'd also need to use `b"\n".join`, not `"\n".join` so types match.

Comment: `content` is a `bytes`, so `i` is an integer, and `"Error" in i` attempts to iterate over `i`.

Comment: Thank you @wjandrea and ShadowRanger. It worked.

Comment: @vvazza Excellent! Now, you're getting downvotes because: 1) You don't seem to have tried any debugging, e.g. checking what `content` is. 2) The error is not occurring "while writing to another file" but actually while scanning the first file. 3) You haven't really asked a question, though there is an implicit, `How do I fix "argument of type 'int' is not iterable"?` So please read [ask]. For debugging in the future, make a [mre] with complete but minimal code, example input, expected output, and actual output or the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) rather than [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline), *or* iterate over the lines, like so:

```
with open(self.filePath, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = [i for i in content_file if b"Error" in i]
content = b"\n".join(content)
```

Iterating over `bytes` objects gives `int` objects, and the `in` operator falls back on iterating over its second argument if it does not have a `__contains__` magic method.

Comment: I'd suggest removing `'rb'`, then just use `"Error" in i`